# C# javascript files httphandler

Tags: javascript, c#, master-pages, httphandler

I currently have a httpHandler in my application to change the path of the js files as they are requested. This works for some js files but not if they are requested from the master pages. Any ideas how to fix this?

Code:

Master Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

Handler:

```
public class handler : IHttpHandler
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
           //DO STUFF
     }

     public bool IsReusable {get; private set; }
}
```

Web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.js" type="namespace.handler, namespace" />
</httpHandlers>
<handlers>
    <add name="JsHandler" path="*.js" verb="*" type="namespace.handler" resourceType="Unspecified" precondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your aim is just to change the requested file path, I would definitely prefer to declare an [UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing) rule into *web.config* over an **IHttpHandler**

In this way, your paths will be managed directly from IIS (that should be more reliable as well faster); furthermore, you can then disable the [RAMMFAR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) for your application.

Comment: How would i do this? I am not too familiar with doing this kind of thing. and just for instance, i may have paths like js/"versionnumber"/file.js. how would i define these rules? sorry bit of a newbie haha

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, js/{versionNumber}/jfile.js needs to be js/jfile.js

Comment: The Url rewrite module is very flexible, and you can for sure find a pattern that will suite your needs.

I suggest you to have a read [to the official guide](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: And urlrewriting works for javascript files which are requested when a page loads yes? not just for the url of the webpage?

Comment: I have tried the following `<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite JS">
          <match url="^js/v~([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+).js" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="js/{R:2}.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>` but it does not load the config then. there seems to be issues reading it. are any external files required?

Comment: Url Rewriting takes place even before your web application is hit.

Note that if using IIS tab manager, you should have got also a [URL tester](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns) as well a log of rules matches

Comment: Im not using iis im just putting it straight into web config